# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider with typescript service

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a simple service that returns 3 strings (  2 strings optional )

```
module app.common {

interface IPageElementService {
    pageEl: app.domain.IPageSettings;
    setPageElements(title: string, subTitle?: string,icon?:string): 
                    app.domain.IPageSettings;
}

export class PageElementService implements IPageElementService {

    constructor(public pageEl: app.domain.IPageSettings) {
    }

    setPageElements(title: string, subTitle?: string,icon?:string): 
                    app.domain.IPageSettings {
        return this.pageEl = {
            title:title,
            subTitle:subTitle,
            icon:icon
       }
    }
}
angular.module("common.services").service("pageElementService", PageElementService);
}
```

This uses the pageSettings set as

```
module app.domain {
export interface IPageSettings {
    title     : string;
    subTitle? : string;
    icon?     : string;
}

export class PageSettings implements IPageSettings {
    constructor(public title     : string,
                public subTitle? : string,
                public icon?     : string
    ) {
    }
  }
}
```

This is then added to the common.services custom module

```
 module app.common {
 angular.module("common.services", [
    "ngResource"
 ])
}
```

This module is added to the main module

```
module app {
  angular.module("app", [
    // Angular
    "ui.router",
    "ngMaterial",
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngMessages",
    "ngCookies",
    // Custom
    "common.services",
 ]);
}
```

However i cannot seem to use the `PageElementService` in any of my controllers and i get the error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: pageElProvider <- pageEl <- pageElementService
```

This makes little sense as i have another service on that module that works 100%.

this is the controller

```
module app.home {
  interface IHomeModel {
      loader          : boolean;
      projectSettings : app.values.IProjectValues;
  }

  export class HomeCtrl implements IHomeModel {

      static $inject = ["$timeout","$state","pageElementService"];
      constructor(private $timeout       : angular.ITimeoutService,
                  private $state         : angular.ui.IStateService,
                  private pageElements   : app.common.PageElementService,
                  public loader          : boolean,
                  public projectSettings : app.values.IProjectValues
    ) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.loader = true;

        console.log(this.pageElements.setPageElements("Home"));

        $timeout(function () {
            vm.projectSettings = this.projectSettings;
            vm.loader = false;
        }, 500); 
    }
  }
  angular.module("app").controller("homeCtrl", HomeCtrl);
 }
```

Comment: well, where is implementation of your `IPageSettings`? because that is what your constructor expects to be injected...

Comment: Well, that snippet just implements interface - good, but not enough. You have to register that for angular as you did with `.service("pageElementService"...` - tried to show that in detail below

Answer (score 1):

You just didn't register a service named 'pageEl' (that implements app.domain.IPageSettings).

```js
module.service("pageEl", ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The registered service `PageElementService`

```
.service("pageElementService", PageElementService);
```

requires in its constructor dependency

```
constructor(public pageEl: app.domain.IPageSettings) {
```

and we must register that

```
export class PageSettings implements IPageSettings {
}
...
.service("pageEl", PageSettings);
```

And also, to be ready for minification we should do

```
static $inject = ["pageEl"];
constructor(public pageEl: app.domain.IPageSettings) {
```

Another solution, how to get/create `IPageSettings`, is manually, not via IoC coming with angular. E.g., if we know all the settings (title and subTitle and icon) we can change the constructor of the `PageElementService`:

```
public pageEl: app.domain.IPageSettings;
//constructor(public pageEl: app.domain.IPageSettings) {
constructor(){
  this.pageEl = new PageSettings(....)
}
```

But as expressed in comments - any argument required by our service must be registered in angular IoC...

Comment: Im so confused . I now have the error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: titleProvider <- title <- pageSettings`

Comment: Correct. Becuase you've just registered "pageEl" which requires three arguments to be passed via constructor injection. So even these must be registered... That is really standard issue - if you ask the IoC framework to create new objects and provide them with their dependencies (title, subTitle) you must register even these. If those objects should not be registered.. and you know them, you can just create such object yourself... will try to show

Comment: new error `cannot use "new" with an expression whose type lacks a call or constructor` . I was just creating this without a service, which i think i am just going to revert back to until i understand how to properly write typescript services